# access data from database to compare with current date to calculate total days

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.6

I have tried to access date stored in my db table and compare it with current date so that I can get the number of days but it shows this error

`DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string ([{&quot;quit_date&quot;:null},{&quot;quit_date&quot;:null}]) at position 0 ([): Unexpected character`

This is the code that use in my controller

```
$quit_date = Information::select('quit_date')
             ->where('user_id','=',\Auth::user()->id)
             ->get();
$date = new Carbon($quit_date);
$now = Carbon::now();
        $day = $date->diffInDays($now);
```

but if I set the `$quit_date` manually with the date for example **"2019-04-25 00:00:00.000000"**, the code works fine and shows the days different between the dates, but when I use the `Information::select` to read the date from database, it shows error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    use Auth;     //top of controller
    $checkdate = Information::
            ->where('user_id','=',Auth::user()->id)
            ->first();
    $quit_date=$checkdate->quit_date;
    $date = new Carbon($quit_date);
    $now = Carbon::now();
    $day = $date->diffInDays($now);
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue occurs because you are using `->get()` at the end of your query. That method returns a `Collection` not a single object. The issue is solved by using `->first()` to return a single object.

The error itself is because in the line `$date = new Carbon($quit_date);`, Carbon cannot convert a `Collection` to a date.

This should work:

```
$quit_date = Information::select('quit_date')
             ->where('user_id','=', \Auth::user()->id)
             ->first();    //Changed this from ->get()
$date = new Carbon($quit_date);
$now = Carbon::now();
$day = $date->diffInDays($now);
```